# Inserting records into a table with multiple foreign keys with Eloquent

Tags: php, foreign-keys, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've just started to learn Laravel 4 and I've run in to a small problem and I'm very curious to if there is a solution. I have a multilingual recipe database and I have, in short, modeled my database like this:

```php
Schema::create('language', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id', 2)->primary();
    $table->string('display_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('recipe', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('translated_recipe', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipe')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('language_id', 2);
    $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('language');
    $table->string('translated_name')
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My models look like this:

```php
class Language extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'language';
    public function translatedRecipes() {
        return $this->hasMany('TranslatedRecipe');
    }
}

class Recipe extends Eloquent { 
    protected $table = 'recipe';
    public function translations() {
        return $this->hasMany('TranslatedRecipe');
    }
}

class TranslatedRecipe extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'translated_recipe';
    public function recipe() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Recipe');
    }
}
```

Then I have some basic seeding:

```php
Language::create(array('id' => 'en', 'display_name' => 'English'));
Recipe::create(array('name' => 'First Recipe', 'slug' => 'first_recipe'));
```

Here come's the tricky part. How do I insert a translated recipe with Eloquent? I've come this far:

```php
$recipe = Recipe::all()->first();
$lang = Language::all()->first();
$translatedRecipe = new TranslatedRecipe;
$translatedRecipe->translated_name = $lang->display_name.' '.$recipe->name;
```

I can easily do an INSERT with the Query Builder:

```php
DB::table('translated_recipe')->insert(
    array(
        'recipe_id' => $recipe->id, 
        'language_id' => $lang->id,
        'translated_name' => $translatedRecipe->translated_name
    )
);
```

It doesn't set the timestamps though because I'm guessing that's a feature of Eloquent. Is there a way to keep it 100% Eloquent? I can't do this:

```php
$translatedRecipe = $recipe->translations()->save($translatedRecipe);
```

...because SQL throws an "Integrity constraint violation: 1452..." error because of the missing second foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I haven't tested this but there are a few things I would change:

- I would change the '**language**' table to have the following fields: '**id**', '**initials**'  and '**displayname**'.
- I would then change the '**language_id**' field in '**translated_recipe**' table to be an unsigned integer.

(It's really brave to have your primary key set to 'id' in the 'language' table - and it's not even an id by the loose meaning of the word! This is possibly the cause of the problem. Eloquent might be expecting your primary key to be the auto-incremented field which you don't have.)

Also, it's nice to make full use of the 'free' features provided in the framework at a relatively small 'fee' of following conventions such as:

1. naming your tables in plural form (languages, recipes, translations)
2. setting your primary key to be the auto-incremented field (obviously an integer)

You can scroll to the **One to Many** section of [Dayle Rees Codehappy tutorial](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/eloquent-orm) which was meant for Laravel 3 but is fit for our purpose. Or spare a buck or two for his [CodeBright](https://leanpub.com/codebright) book for Laravel 4 if you want to learn other features of the framework. (I haven't yet)

Lastly, you don't have 'short_description' and 'description' fields in your 'translated_recipe' table! It's a miracle it's working at all!

```
        Schema::create('languages', function($table) 
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('initials', 2)->unique();
        $table->string('display_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('recipes', function($table) 
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('translations', function($table) 
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('language_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('translated_name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipe')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('language')->onDelete('cascade');          
    });
```

**Models**

```
class Language extends Eloquent {
  public function translations() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Translation');
  }
}

class Recipe extends Eloquent { 
  public function translations() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Translation');
  }
}

class Translation extends Eloquent {
  public function recipe() 
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('Recipe');
  }

  public function language() 
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('Language');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on column naming and ids! One thing I don't get though. I'm pretty new to database modeling, so bear with me here. Why do I need the extra table and the many to many relationship? One recipe can have many translated_recipes and one translated_recipe belongs to one recipe. One translated_recipe can only belong to one language and one language can have many translated_recipes. Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: You are totally right! (I'll edit my answer). You actually don't need a fourth table.